# Python regex - how to detect repetitions

Tags: python, regex

For these strings, I'd like to extract all the b's .

```
'aaaabbbbcccc' => bbbb
'aaaaaaaabbbbbbbcccccc' => bbbbbbb
'abc' => b
'aaaab' => b
'bc' => b
```

I've tried something like that:

```
re.search(r'a*(\w+)c*','aaaabbbbcccc').groups() => ('bbbbccc',)
```

Comment: I am confused. In the title you mention repetitions, while in your text you have examples without repetitions (`'abc'` and `'bc'`). What exactly do you mean by "repetition"?

Comment: ... and why to you refer to "at the end of string" when none of your examples show a match at the ends of those strings?

Comment: Sorry, you're right, the title was confused.  I've edited it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a negated character class. `[^ac]` matches any character but not of `a` or `c`

```
>>> re.search(r'a*([^ac]+)c*','aaaabbbbcccc').group(1)
'bbbb'
>>> re.search(r'a*([^ac]+)c*','aaaaaaaabbbbbbbcccccc').group(1)
'bbbbbbb'
>>> re.search(r'a*([^ac]+)c*','abc').group(1)
'b'
>>> re.search(r'a*([^ac]+)c*','aaaab').group(1)
'b'
>>> re.search(r'a*([^ac]+)c*','bc').group(1)
'b'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply just use `[b]*` but in a grouping but note that you need `group(1)` :

```
>>> re.search(r'a*([b]+)c*','aabbbbbbbaa').group(1)
```